# CAB installer cannot copy System.dll, mscorlib.dll and mscorlib.tlb

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, cab

When installing my application, using a CAB installer, it fails to copy System.dll, mscorlib.dll and mscorlib.tlb and then fails to install.

I created a Windows Forms Application that I want to run in device running Windows CE 5.0.
I followed the instructions [here](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html) to create the .cab installer.

Comment: It should fail, don't copy any files that belong to the .NETFramework install.  The tutorial doesn't tell you to do this, don't.

Comment: I am a newbie with this technology, but I did not chose to copy those files I think, I followed exactly the tutorial steps. When I click on the CAB Installer and it starts installing it fails when copying these files. I just tried removing those 3 libraries from the dependencies on the CAB project and the error goes away and it installs normally. When I click on to open the app, it says that it cannot find one of its components.

Comment: Ok, I just managed to install correctly with all the dependencies, but when I try to open the app, the error about not finding one of its components appears again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was having trouble with my network (I was executing the .cab installer directly from it). When I first copied the files to a local path it installed perfectly.